# Getting contacts error - how to fix that?

Tags: java, android, contacts

My problem is that I am listing contacts, the phone numbers show up just fine however I can not get the names to work.

I have tried several ways to gain the 'DISPLAY_NAME' however none of them have worked

```
    private void initializeRecyclerView() {
        mUserList = findViewById(R.id.userList);
        mUserList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        mUserList.setHasFixedSize(false);
        mUserListLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false);
        mUserList.setLayoutManager(mUserListLayoutManager);
        mUserListAdapter = new UserListAdapter(userList);
        mUserList.setAdapter(mUserListAdapter);
        getContactsList();
    }

This is my adaptor ^^

    private void getContactsList(){
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while(phones.moveToNext()){
            String phone = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

            UserObject mContact = new UserObject(name, phone);
            userList.add(mContact);
            mUserListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i am getting the contacts with this :-

```
private void getContactsList(){
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while(phones.moveToNext()){
            String phone = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
 UserObject mContact = new UserObject(name, phone);
            userList.add(mContact);
        }

 mUserListAdapter = new UserListAdapter(userList);
    mUserList.setAdapter(mUserListAdapter);
    }
```

and also set the permission for get contacts :-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: leave a comment if you have any query

Comment: Thats great however when I implement your code the 'contactList' is red, what do I need to put to fix that?

Comment: brother contact list is my arrayList just add your list in this code and try

Comment: I am still a little bit confused, Could you edit the script to sent to use my 'userList'

Comment: where are you setting your adapter ?

Comment: I am setting my adaptor above this segment

Comment: where can i send it then?

Comment: have you call this method ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `PROJECTION`

You can put this method in your code

```
 public Cursor getContact(Context context) {
        String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
               };
        Uri uri = CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

        String order = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";// LIMIT " + limit + " offset " + lastId + "";
        try {
            return context.getContentResolver().query(uri, PROJECTION, null, null, order);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And get name using

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
```

Happy coding

Comment: Okay, but at the end where can I add name and phonenumber to my array list?

Comment: Please check now

Comment: All good apart from 'context' is in red, what should I do about that?

Comment: You need to pass Context as parameter